# C# Decimal.Parse comma problems

Tags: c#

I need to parse a `string` to a `decimal` and it might be used in the UK or a european culture.

If in a european culture `2,00` would be `2`

However, `2,00` would be invalid in the UK culture as a comma denotes a thousand.

If i use

```
Double.Parse("20,50", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

it returns `2050`

I would have expected this to throw an invalid exception.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I am getting `2050`, not `20.50`. Have you changed the settings of the UK regional settings in the control panel and set the decimal separator to `,`?

Comment: My default settings in control panel are English (United Kingdom) and Decimal Symbol is .

Comment: Even if you get 2050, that is still incorrect as far as im concerned, it should throw it out as invalid format.

Comment: It may be incorrect as far as _you_ are concerned, but that's that _expected_ behaviour. What is the default culture of the account that this is running under? Has that account changed the settings?

Comment: I was mistaken, i do get 2050, but this still seems wrong to me.  And it definatley is wrong for my users.  Their in a GB locale and it shouldnt allow them to enter invalid figures.  adding a comma in this location is invalid?

Comment: You might think so, but that's not how it works. The parser is tolerant to the location of the `,` - probably because it serves [two purposes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierTh). If a string shouldn't contain `,` you need to test yourself and throw.

Answer (score 3):

You *should* not be getting an exception, as `,` is a valid character in the parse string (as you said, it is interpreted as the thousands separator).

However, I am seeing `2050` for the same piece of code, not `20.50`.

I would expect to see your result for the `en-GB` culture only if those have been manually changed in the control panel for that region (so if someone set the decimal separator to `,` and the thousands separator to something that is not `,`).

Comment: I think the question is: Why is this code working? not how to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

The point is that "2,00" in GB culutre should be invalid but it parses it like it was using a european culture.

I want it to throw an exception.

In contrast - Double.Parse("20.50", new CultureInfo("fr-FR")) throws an exception as the decimal place is invalid.

So why isnt this true for Double.Parse("20,50", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))

Answer (score 0):

From the updated question, I can tell that UK culture posiibly uses `,` character as a possible places separation character, like `2,000` standing for `2000`, and `2,000,000` for `2000000`. But it can also be like `2,0,0,0` and it still be `2000`.

From that point of view there are 3 possible scenarios:

1. you are always recieving data in a local format, then there is no problem, you just parse string as it is (however there is one gotcha - user can change string formatting options, so you better crate new default local culture).
2. you are recieving data in predefined format, then you use some fixed culture to parse string.
3. you are recieving data in unknown format relatively to local, i.e. you can receive both local and non-local culture formats. This is the worst case, and there is no generic solution to this. I suggest reducing this to case 2 or 1, depending this task is easier.

Comment: The point is, eventually i will be using the CurrentCulture or the UI culture rather than newing one so im not sure if this will help.